# Do I need to redirect my "A" DNS too?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns, godaddy, nameserver

I'm trying to redirect my GoDaddy's domain to another hosting.

I have added the name servers, but the hosting website says "You can also point your domain ("A" DNS record) to this IP: [ip here]".

Should I do both name servers and "A" DNS? Or is it enough with the name servers?

Comment: "Redirect" is a confusing word here. Are you trying to transfer your domain to another registrar, or are you trying to move a website to another host/server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nameservers are enough and better.

In fact, in case your web hosting changes your IP address (because you haven't a static IP and you're on a shared host), thanks to nameserver you wouldn't need to change record A.

Answer (score 1):

If your host takes care of the DNS when you've changed your nameservers, it should be fine.

Changing the 'A' record in your control panel wouldn't have any effect because your nameservers don't point to them anymore...